# Devices in VLAN can't obtain IP address from DHCP server

Tags: routing, switch, wireless, vlan, dhcp

I'd like to build the company network with a L2 Switch.

Here are the requirements.

- Marketing team's computers and the visitors's mobile devices need to access the Internet.
- Other business computers and employee's mobile devices can't access the Internet.
- visitor's mobile devices can't access all computers of company such as marketing team's computers and other business computers.
- Employee's mobile devices need to access the business computer.
- Visitor's mobile devices and Employee's mobile devices use the WiFi Access Points together.

Unfortunately my L2 switch (Huawei S2700) has not DHCP Server function.
So I made the network configuration as following.

[image: Network Diagram for my computer]

Marketing team's computers can obtain IP address well.

But sometimes the visitor's mobile devices can't obtain IP address from DHCP server.

What problem is this?

Employee's mobile devices obtain IP Address as I tested, but I can't sure this always will be worked.

I configured all ports as hybrid port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your topology, visitor's vlan is 40.
I cannot see which DHCP server is serving that scope - is it the access point ?

### Suggestions

If you have multiple VLANs and hence need multiple DHCP scopes:

1) I would connect have 1 single DHCP server connected to the router
2) make the uplink port from switch to router as TRUNK
3) then configure DHCP RELAY for all the different VLANs
4) the DHCP server would serve all the scopes

Comment: DHCP Server (VLAN 10, 192.168.30.1) will serve the VLAN 30 and VLAN 40. From the macketing team and visitor's devices to 192.168.30.1, ping is okay. I checked. And this switch has not DHCP relay agent feature.

Comment: If the huawei is only functionning at Layer2, I do not think you can create switched interfaces on it to configure the DHCP relay agent feature. You probably should check your configs, switchports and run a sniffer like wireshark to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the VLAN tagging issue above, You may want to look at you access point in more detail. The L2 switch should be fine as long as your VLAN tags match up, but you may find that depending on how your AP handles traffic (what is it, router? Dumb Cisco AP?), it may need some sort of [DHCP Relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_relaying) or a settings adjustment to place it into AP mode.